# Jenkins : getting error when we try to send notification from Jenkins : error "550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain"

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins : getting error when we try to send notification from Jenkins : error "550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain"

Check the full error :
Not sent to the following valid addresses: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com admin
SMTPSendFailedException message: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.

Next SMTPSenderFailedException message: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.

QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection u13sm8039654pfi.51 - gsmtp
Finished: SUCCESS

++++++++++

```
Checking for post-build
Performing post-build step
Checking if email needs to be generated
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending mail from default account using System Admin e-mail address
messageContentType = text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Collecting change authors...
    build: 32
Adding recipients from project recipient list
Analyzing: prakashranas555@gmail.com
Looking for: prakashranasinghe@gmail.com
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com
    => found type: 0
Analyzing: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com
Looking for: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com
    => found type: 0
Analyzing: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com
Looking for: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com
    => found type: 0
Adding admin with address admin
Analyzing: admin
Looking for: admin
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: admin
    => found type: 0
Analyzing: admin
Looking for: admin
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: admin
    => found type: 0
Analyzing: admin
Looking for: admin
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: admin
    => found type: 0
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com admin
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP u13sm8039654pfi.51 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 25
EHLO Prakashr.Direct.local
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [123.231.87.10]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<nobody@nowhere>
550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 550, with response: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.

RSET
250 2.1.5 Flushed u13sm8039654pfi.51 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2374)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1808)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1285)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:539)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:444)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:354)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:21)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:808)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:189)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1958)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:100)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:433)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1817)
    ... 12 more
Not sent to the following valid addresses: prakashranasinghe555@gmail.com admin
SMTPSendFailedException message: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.

Next SMTPSenderFailedException message: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain.

QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection u13sm8039654pfi.51 - gsmtp
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [an answer at ServerFault to *SMTP Server 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name*](https://serverfault.com/a/529214/249782) it's probably the line:

```
EHLO Prakashr.Direct.local
```

which doesn't have an [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).